# How to manage certificates using OpenSSL in c++?

Tags: c++, openssl, certificate, stunnel

I need to manage certificates and containers using openssl in c++, and create stunnel.
How can I do this? I've been trying to find any examples or instructions on the internet but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you really want to do, but they show a good example on the openssl library here: [Stackoverflow: openssl-in-c-socket-connection-https-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229601/openssl-in-c-socket-connection-https-client)